# Wait for inner code to finish before looping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have a for loop that I would like to run 10 times. It downloads a 3MB file off my server then returns the time (in ms) it took and I will do that 10 times and take the average as the client's download speed.

However, when I run this loop:

```
$scope.startTest = function () {
    var dlTime = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var wait = getLargeData();
        wait.then(function(result) {
            dlTime += result.dlTime;
            $scope.message += "\n finished loop " + i;
        });
    }
    $scope.message += "\n Total download time: " + dlTime;
}
```

it prints out the following:

```
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
finished loop 10
Total download time: 0
```

I know my problem has to do with asychronization but how can I make the loop wait on the .then call before moving on?

Edit: getLargeData() does return a promise

```
function getLargeData() {
    var loadTime = 0;
    var dlSpeed = 0;
    var promise = $q.defer();
    var startTime = new Date();
    $networkSvc.getLargeData()
        .success(function (data) {
            loadTime = new Date() - startTime;
            dlSpeed = 3 / (loadTime / 1000);
            var ret = { loadTime: loadTime, dlSpeed: dlSpeed };
            promise.resolve(ret);
            return promise.promise;
        })
        .error(function() {
            $scope.message = "Error - could not contact server.";
        });
    return promise.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $q.all

```
    let promises = [promiseAlpha(), promiseBeta(), promiseGamma()];

$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values[0]); // value alpha
    console.log(values[1]); // value beta
    console.log(values[2]); // value gamma

    complete();
});
```

It takes array of promises and values is array of completed promises. 
[Here](http://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/) is something about.

The code you wrote write 10 for ten times, because that are promises which wait for data, but i variable goes before finish. 
q.all is for resolving these ten promises. You can iterate in this scope.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you! Only problem I have is I'm getting skewed data now because all 10 calls will start at the same time and most of the time I get back is time spent blocked waiting.

Comment: One time i made my server side method in java synchronized. Now we have this situation in company and it's possible to wait for first promise result, and then make another call. In second approach you may look for "promise chaining"

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of the `$q` service of angular. Use that in your `getLargeData()` function and have that function return a promise upon completion. You can than benefit from it as such `getLargeData().then( ...` [Read more about it in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) and the first example is a good point to start.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Either

1. Get rid of asynchronous calls which will lead to the fact that your users really wait (by the way you won't download then in parallel)
2. Use `Promise.all()` (learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)) or similar to the promise (`$q`?) implementation you use. This allows you to make a callback when **all** processes are done.